# >Find the terms which do not contain $7$ between $1000$ and $9999$?

Tags: number-theory

> Find the terms which do not contain $7$ between $1000$ and $9999$.

**MyApproach**

To find Numbers which do not contain $7$

Total numbers=$9$ . $10$ . $10$ . $9$($9999$ cannot come because he said numbers between $1000$ and $9999$).

Now,Nos which contain $7$ at $thousand$ place occurs $1000$  times i.e($7000$,$7001$,$7002$,$7003$...$7999$).

Nos,which $7$ at $hundred$ places occurs $100$ times.

Nos,which $7$ at $tenth$ places occurs $7$ times.

Nos,which $7$ at $unit$ places occurs $1$ times.

=$1171$

$8100$-$1171$=$6929$

But the Ans is $3168$

> Am i right In my approach.Can anyone guide me what mistake I did?

Comment: The number of integers between 1000 and 9999 is not 8100 but 8998 (excluding 1000 and 9999).

Comment: First of all, there are $9998-1001+1=8998$ numbers between $1000$ and $9999$

Comment: @JackFrost  Thousand place can have 9 numbers from $1$-$9$. so 9 numbers.Why my approach is wrong?

Comment: Looks like the answer is wrong and it should be 5830

Comment: @justintakro: According to your method it has to be $9*10*10*10$ including both 1000 and 9999 but since we are looking for numbers between we have $9*10*10*10-2=8998$.

Comment: How does numbers with 7 at units place is only 1??

Comment: @cr001 what you subtracted from 8998?

Comment: Look at barak manos' answer. There is no need to substract anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st digit can be any of the following $8$ options: $[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]$.

The 2nd digit can be any of the following $9$ options: $[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,0]$.

The 3rd digit can be any of the following $9$ options: $[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,0]$.

The 4th digit can be any of the following $9$ options: $[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,0]$.

Hence the total amount of $4$-digit numbers without seven is $8\cdot9\cdot9\cdot9=5832$.

Comment: Is 9999 and 1000?I think not  acceptable ?But they can come in your approach?

Comment: @justintakro: Well, if you think the question meant "excluding $1000$ and $9999$", then you can always subtract $2$ from the result. Personally, I don't think that's what the question meant. It sounds more like it meant "any $4$-digit decimal number".

Comment: Yes,but I think between meant excluding those numbers?Otherwise I will check the options:)

Comment: @justintakro: Like I said, if it meant "excluding", then you need to subtract $2$. In any case, I think you're dealing with "nit picking". The main purpose of the question is to resolve it as described above. Subtracting $2$ or not subtracting $2$ - there's nothing too difficult about it, it's just a matter of definition (and BTW, it could just as well be "excluding only one of them", so I think, unless explicitly mentioned, those $2$ numbers should in fact **BE** included).